# How do I commit a SVN deletion after parent directory is no longer under version control?

Tags: svn, version-control, commit

I am cleaning up a Subversion directory, including deleting a jquery-ui directory (already committed I thought) and moving the contents of a subdirectory to its parent. (I am working from a Linux command line.)

The last of a long string of attempted workarounds gives:

```
jonathan@machine:~/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms/static$ svn update jquery-ui
At revision 53.
jonathan@machine:~/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms/static$ svn delete jquery-ui
D         jquery-ui
jonathan@machine:~/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms/static$ svn commit jquery-ui
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/svn/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms/static' path not found
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn:    '/home/jonathan/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms/static/svn-commit.2.tmp'
```

So I try to register the directory with source control:

```
jonathan@machine:~/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms/static$ cd ..
jonathan@machine:~/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms$ svn add static
svn: warning: 'static' is already under version control
jonathan@machine:~/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms$ svn commit static
...
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File 'static/jquery-ui' is out of date
svn: '/svn/coms_poc_ajax/!svn/wrk/a41dde0b-6ccd-43cf-80d6-c237fc63ceda/trunk/coms/static/jquery-ui' path not found
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn:    '/home/jonathan/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms/svn-commit.3.tmp'
```

What do I need to do to exorcise the ghost of the jquery-ui directory and get back to committing updates normally?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the directory directly in the repository if you specify the complete URI.

Suppose your directory is at https://mysvn/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms/static/jquery-ui you could use the following statement to remove it.

```
svn rm https://mysvn/svn3/coms_poc_ajax/trunk/coms/static/jquery-ui -m"removing jquery-ui"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both answers and was still fighting Subversion. I made a fresh checkout and that seemed to eliminate the discrepancy between server and my copy about whether directory X should exist (at least for now).